# How to retrieve form values from a React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, typescript

I want to retrieve the values from a `<form>` element when a user submits the form. I  do not want to use `onChange` listener and setting the values in the state. How can I accomplish this?

**login.tsx**

```
...

interface LoginProps {
    authService: Auth
}

export default class Login extends React.Component<LoginProps, {}> {

    constructor(props: LoginProps, context: any) {
        super(props, context);

        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    private onSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // how can I retrieve the username and password value from the FormEvent

        this.props.authService.authenticate(username, password)
    }

    render(): React.ReactNode {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="col align-self-center">
                    <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <img className="mb-4" src={Logo} height={72}/>
                        <label htmlFor="input_username">Gebruikersnaam</label>
                        <input type="text" id="input_username" className="form-control" required={true}
                               autoFocus={true} tabIndex={1}/>
                        <label htmlFor="input_password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="input_password" className="form-control" required={true}
                               tabIndex={2}/>
                        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" tabIndex={3}>Aanmelden
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you want to use onChange?

Comment: @jsw324 just experimenting; It feels like it adds unnecessary complexity and would look cleaner I think

Comment: you can use onChange and set local state based on the name of the input, so it's just one handler for both input values. something like `this.setState({ [inputName]: [inputValue] })`

Comment: @jsw324 I am trying to avoid the whole push/pull mechanism for value retrieval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then get it by the id 'input_username' and 'input_password' or by ref using React.createRef()

Answer (score -1):

To get the first field:

```
e.target[0].value
```